# PHP keeping session logged on after link

Tags: php, mysql

I have written a page that displays a load of data from MySQL database and all works perfect EXCEPT that when i click the Home link (the title of the page) it logs out and i need to log back in, im probably missing something stupid or not doing something i need, code below

```
<?php
session_start();
?><title>Vend365 Monitor (Beta test)</title>
<h1><u><a href="http://www.codeman.org/v365.php">Vend 365 online monitor (Beta test)</a><p></p></u></h3>
<?php
require_once ("V365Connect.php");
//Following if 'update' is clicked
if (isset($_POST['lastseen'])){?><p>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: left;    
}
</style>
<h1>Vend 'Last Seen' times: Page loaded at <?php echo date("d/m/Y G:i:s"); ?></h1>
    <?php
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT distinct customer FROM vends order by customer") or die(mysql_error());  
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) 
  {  echo '<table><th>';
    ?><font size = "5">Customer - '<?php echo $row[customer];?>'</font><?php
    echo '</th>';
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vends where customer ='".$row[customer]."'") or die(mysql_error());  
  while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
 {
    echo '<tr><td>';
    ?>Machine <b>'<?php echo $row1[machine];?>'</b> last seen online at <b>'<?php echo $row1[lastseen];?>'</b> running version <b>'<?php echo $row1[myversion];?>'</b><?php
    $today = date("d/m/Y G:i:s");
    $lastseentime = $row1[lastseen];
    $diff = $today-$lastseentime;
    if ($diff == "1"){
    ?><b> <font color = "red"> -- Last seen online yesterday</font></b> <?php ;}
    if ($diff > "1"){
    ?> <b><font color = "red"> -- Last seen online BEFORE yesterday</font></b> <?php ;}
    echo '</td></tr><p>' ;
 }
 }?></table>
<?php
}else{
if (isset($_POST['update'])){
if ($_POST['checkbox']=='checked'){
$isalive = 1;
} else {
$isalive = 0;
}
if ($_POST['checkbox1']=='checked'){
$hb800 = 1;
} else {
$hb800 = 0;
}
if ($_POST['checkbox2']=='checked'){
$hb1100 = 1;
} else {
$hb1100 = 0;
}
if ($_POST['checkbox3']=='checked'){
$hb1400 = 1;
} else {
$hb1400 = 0;
}
if ($_POST['checkbox4']=='checked'){
$hb1700 = 1;
} else {
$hb1700 = 0;
}
if ($_POST['checkbox5']=='checked'){
$gcmreboot = 1;
} else {
$gcmreboot = 0;
}
if ($_POST['checkbox6']=='checked'){
$emailreboot = 1;
} else {
$emailreboot = 0;
}
if ($_POST['checkbox7']=='checked'){
$hbgcm = 1;
} else {
$hbgcm = 0;
}
if ($_POST['checkbox8']=='checked'){
$hbemail = 1;
} else {
$hbemail = 0;
}
if ($_POST['checkbox9']=='checked'){
$edigcm = 1;
} else {
$edigcm = 0;
}
if ($_POST['checkbox10']=='checked'){
$ediemail = 1;
} else {
$ediemail = 0;
}
if ($_POST['checkbox11']=='checked'){
$reportgcm = 1;
} else {
$reportgcm = 0;
}
if ($_POST['checkbox12']=='checked'){
$reportemail = 1;
} else {
$reportemail = 0;
}
if ($_POST['checkbox13']=='checked'){
$pingmailgcm = 1;
} else {
$pingmailgcm = 0;
}
if ($_POST['checkbox14']=='checked'){
$pingmailemail = 1;
} else {
$pingmailemail = 0;
}
if ($_POST['checkbox15']=='checked'){
$internetgcm = 1;
} else {
$internetgcm = 0;
}
if ($_POST['checkbox16']=='checked'){
$internetemail= 1;
} else {
$internetemail = 0;
}
if ($_POST['checkbox17']=='checked'){
$sqlgcm = 1;
} else {
$sqlgcm = 0;
}
if ($_POST['checkbox18']=='checked'){
$sqlemail = 1;
} else {
$sqlemail = 0;
}
if ($_POST['checkbox19']=='checked'){
$backupgcm = 1;
} else {
$backupgcm = 0;
}
if ($_POST['checkbox20']=='checked'){
$backupemail = 1;
} else {
$backupemail = 0;
}
$sqlupdate = "update vends set isalive='".$isalive."',customer='".$_POST['customer']."',machine='".$_POST['machine']."',mailserver='".$_POST['smtp']."',emails='".$_POST['emails']."',gcm='".$_POST['gcm']."',hb800='".$hb800."',hb1100='".$hb1100."',hb1400='".$hb1400."',hb1700='".$hb1700."',sqlserver='".$_POST['sqlserver']."',sqlport='".$_POST['sqlport']."',sqlinstance='".$_POST['sqlinstance']."',sqldatabase='".$_POST['sqldatabase']."',sqlname='".$_POST['sqlname']."',sqlpassword='".$_POST['sqlpassword']."',rebootgcm='".$gcmreboot."',rebootemail='".$emailreboot."',hbgcm='".$hbgcm."',hbemail='".$hbemail."',edigcm='".$edigcm."',ediemail='".$ediemail."',reportgcm='".$reportgcm."',reportemail='".$reportemail."',mailpinggcm='".$pingmailgcm."',mailpingemail='".$pingmailemail."',internetgcm='".$internetgcm."',internetemail='".$internetemail."',sqlgcm='".$sqlgcm."',sqlemail='".$sqlemail."',backupgcm='".$backupgcm."',backupemail='".$backupemail."',lastseen='".$lastseen."' where mac='".$_SESSION['mac']."'";
mysql_query($sqlupdate) or die(mysql_error());?><h1>
--->Customer -  <font color = blue><?php echo $_SESSION['customer'];?></font>
<br />
--->Machine - <font color = blue><?php echo $_SESSION['machine'];?></font>
<p>
<?php 
echo "Request sent";
}
else
{
//First load screen to select customer when correct details are entered
if (!isset($_POST['update'])){
if (!isset($_POST['customer'])){
if (!isset($_POST['machine'])){
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where user='".$_POST['user']."' and pass='".$_POST['pass']."'") or die(mysql_error()); 
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($count == 1){
?><p><p> <table style="border:1px solid black;"><tr><td><h1>Welcome '<?php echo $_POST['user'];?>'</td></tr></table><?php 
$_SESSION['customer'];
$_SESSION['machine'];
$_SESSION['mac'];
if (!isset($_POST['customer'])) {
if (!isset($_POST['machine'])) {
echo "<h1><form action ='' method='post'>";
echo "Please Select Your Customer<br />";
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT distinct customer FROM vends order by customer") or die(mysql_error());  
 echo "<select name='customer'>"; 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) 
 { 
    echo "<option value = '".$row[customer]."'>".$row[customer]."</option>"; 
 }
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Go'>";
echo "</form>";
echo "";
echo "Show all 'Last Seen' times";
?>
<form method='post'>
<input type='submit' value='Show Last Seen Status' name ='lastseen' />
</form>
<?php
}
}}else {
// If wrong details entered
echo "Sorry, wrong username or password, please go back and try again";
}
} else {
// Following is first time load screen
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML> <html> 
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-sign.css"> 
</head><h1> 
<title>Vend 365 Monitor</title>
<body id="body-color"> 
<div id="Sign-In"> 
<fieldset style="width:30%">
<legend>LOG-IN HERE</legend>

<form method="POST"> User <br><input type="text" style="font-size: 30px;" name="user" size="20"><br> Password <br><input type="password" style="font-size: 30px;" name="pass" size="20"><br> 
<input id="button" type="submit" style="font-size: 30px; "name="submit" value="Log-In"> </form> </fieldset> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html> 
<?php
}}} 
} else {

}
?>
<?php
// Select a vending machine
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])){
 if (isset($_POST['customer'])) {
    $example = $_POST['customer'];
    $_SESSION['customer'] = $example;
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vends where customer='".$example."'") or die(mysql_error()); 
?><h1>
<font color = black>--->Customer - <font color = blue><?php
echo $_SESSION['customer'];?><p></font></font><?php
    echo "<form action ='' method='post'>"; 
echo "Please Select Your Machine<br />";
 echo "<select name='machine'>"; 
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) 
 { 
    echo "<option value = '".$row[machine]."'>".$row[machine]."</option>"; 
 }
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Go'>";
echo "</form>";

    }}
    // show all customer/machine info
 if (isset($_POST['machine'])) {
    $example1 = $_POST['machine'];
    $_SESSION['machine'] = $example1;?>
<h1><font color = black>--->Customer - <font color = blue><?php
echo $_SESSION['customer'];?><br /></font></font><br /><font color = black>--->Machine - <font color = blue><?php
    echo $_SESSION['machine'];  ?><p><?php
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vends where customer='".$_SESSION['customer']."' and machine ='".$_SESSION['machine']."'") or die(mysql_error()); 
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result3))
{
$tag1 = $rows['hb800'];
    $checkedstatus1 = '';
    if($tag1 == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus1 = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus1 = 'unchecked'; 
    }?><font color = black><form method='post'>
0800 Heartbeat check - <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox1' <?php echo $checkedstatus1; ?> />
<br /><?php
$tag2 = $rows['hb1100'];
    $checkedstatus2 = '';
    if($tag2 == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus2 = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus2 = 'unchecked'; 
    }?>
1100 Heartbeat check- <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox2' <?php echo $checkedstatus2; ?> />
<br />
<?php $tag3 = $rows['hb1400'];
    $checkedstatus3 = '';
    if($tag3 == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus3 = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus3 = 'unchecked'; 
    }?>
1400 Heartbeat check - <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox3' <?php echo $checkedstatus3; ?> />
<br />
<?php 
$tag4 = $rows['hb1700'];
    $checkedstatus4 = '';
    if($tag4 == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus4 = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus4 = 'unchecked'; 
    }?>
1700 Heartbeat check - <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox4' <?php echo $checkedstatus4; ?> /><br />
<?php 
$tag5 = $rows['rebootgcm'];
    $checkedstatus5 = '';
    if($tag5 == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus5 = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus5 = 'unchecked'; 
    }?>
Send GCM when rebooted - <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox5' <?php echo $checkedstatus5; ?> /><br />
<?php 
$tag6 = $rows['rebootemail'];
    $checkedstatus6 = '';
    if($tag6 == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus6 = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus6 = 'unchecked'; 
    }?>
Send email when rebooted - <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox6' <?php echo $checkedstatus6; ?> /><br />
<?php 
$tag7 = $rows['hbgcm'];
    $checkedstatus7 = '';
    if($tag7 == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus7 = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus7 = 'unchecked'; 
    }?>
Heartbeat check GCM - <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox7' <?php echo $checkedstatus7; ?> /><br />
<?php 
$tag8 = $rows['hbemail'];
    $checkedstatus8 = '';
    if($tag8 == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus8 = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus8 = 'unchecked'; 
    }?>
Heartbeat check Email - <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox8' <?php echo $checkedstatus8; ?> /><br />
<?php 
$tag9 = $rows['edigcm'];
    $checkedstatus9 = '';
    if($tag9 == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus9 = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus9 = 'unchecked'; 
    }?>
EDI fail check GCM - <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox9' <?php echo $checkedstatus9; ?> /><br />
<?php 
$tag10 = $rows['ediemail'];
    $checkedstatus10 = '';
    if($tag10 == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus10 = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus10 = 'unchecked'; 
    }?>
EDI fail check Email - <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox10' <?php echo $checkedstatus10; ?> /><br />
<?php 
$tag11 = $rows['reportgcm'];
    $checkedstatus11 = '';
    if($tag11 == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus11 = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus11 = 'unchecked'; 
    }?>
Report fail GCM - <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox11' <?php echo $checkedstatus11; ?> /><br />
<?php 
$tag12 = $rows['reportemail'];
    $checkedstatus12 = '';
    if($tag12 == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus12 = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus12 = 'unchecked'; 
    }?>
Report fail Email - <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox12' <?php echo $checkedstatus12; ?> /><br />
<?php 

$gcm = $rows[gcm];
$tag13 = $rows['mailpinggcm'];
    $checkedstatus13 = '';
    if($tag13 == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus13 = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus13 = 'unchecked'; 
    }?>
Ping email server GCM - <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox13' <?php echo $checkedstatus13; ?> /><br />  
<?php 

$tag14 = $rows['mailpingemail'];
    $checkedstatus14 = '';
    if($tag14 == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus14 = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus14 = 'unchecked'; 
    }?>
Ping email server Email - <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox14' <?php echo $checkedstatus14; ?> /><br /> 
<?php 

$tag15 = $rows['internetgcm'];
    $checkedstatus15 = '';
    if($tag15 == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus15 = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus15 = 'unchecked'; 
    }?>
Ping internet fail GCM - <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox15' <?php echo $checkedstatus15; ?> /><br /> 
<?php 

$tag16 = $rows['internetemail'];
    $checkedstatus16 = '';
    if($tag16 == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus16 = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus16 = 'unchecked'; 
    }?>
Ping internet fail email - <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox16' <?php echo $checkedstatus16; ?> /><br /> 
<?php 

$tag17 = $rows['sqlgcm'];
    $checkedstatus17 = '';
    if($tag17 == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus17 = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus17 = 'unchecked'; 
    }?>
Failed SQL ping GCM - <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox17' <?php echo $checkedstatus17; ?> /><br /> 
<?php 

$tag18 = $rows['sqlemail'];
    $checkedstatus18 = '';
    if($tag18 == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus18 = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus18 = 'unchecked'; 
    }?>
Failed SQL ping email - <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox18' <?php echo $checkedstatus18; ?> /><br /> 
<?php 

$tag19 = $rows['backupgcm'];
    $checkedstatus19 = '';
    if($tag19 == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus19 = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus19 = 'unchecked'; 
    }?>
Backup fail GCM - <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox19' <?php echo $checkedstatus19; ?> /><br /> 
<?php 

$tag20 = $rows['backupemail'];
    $checkedstatus20 = '';
    if($tag20 == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus20 = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus20 = 'unchecked'; 
    }?>
Backp fail email - <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox20' <?php echo $checkedstatus20; ?> /><br /> 

<u><b><p>Details</b></u><p>
<?php $_SESSION['mac'] = $rows[mac]; ?>
Mac address - '<?php echo $_SESSION['mac']; ?>'<br />
Customer name - '<?php echo $rows[customer]; ?>'<br />
Machine name - '<?php echo $rows[machine]; ?>'<br />
Current version - '<?php echo $rows[myversion]; ?>'<br />
GCM app code - <input type='text' value='<?php echo $gcm; ?>' size=150 rows=4 name='gcm' />......<br />
SMTP server - '<?php echo $rows[mailserver]; ?>'<br />
Email addresses (seperate by commas) - '<?php echo $rows[emails]; ?>'<br /><p>
<u><b>SQL Credentials</b></u><p>
SQL server - '<?php echo $rows[sqlserver]; ?>'<br />
SQL Port - '<?php echo $rows[sqlport]; ?>'<br />
SQL Instance - '<?php echo $rows[sqlinstance] ?>'<br />
SQL Database - '<?php echo $rows[sqldatabase]; ?>'<br />
SQL User name - '<?php echo $rows[sqlname]; ?>'<br />
SQL Password - '<?php echo $rows[sqlpassword]; ?>' <br /><p>
<p>
<u><b>Alive status</u></b><p>
Last seen online - '<?php echo $rows[lastseen]; ?>'<br />
<?php
$tag = $rows['isalive'];
    $checkedstatus = '';
    if($tag == '1')
    {
      $checkedstatus = 'checked';
    } else {
    $checkedstatus = 'unchecked'; 
    }?>
Request 'IsAlive' status - <input type='checkbox' value='checked' name='checkbox' <?php echo $checkedstatus; ?> /> - This will send a GCM and Email if alive.<p>
<input type='submit' value='Update account details' name ='update' /><p>
</form><p>
    <?php
    }}}}
    ?>
```

Comment: **TL;DR**. Could you please indent properly your code so it gets easy to read?

Comment: TL;DR - could you post only the relevant code?

Comment: Do you have `session_start();` on every page?

Comment: What is this insanity? Not to be overly critical, but this code is completely unreadable and seems to embody the polar opposite of every best practice out there. You need to refactor this aggressively because this thing is out of control. At the very least you need to read a guide on [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) because this is **all wrong**.

Comment: Indent?? sorry dont know what that means.

Comment: @Codeman_cas Indendation is how code is formatted so it's *readable*. There are [tools that do this automatically](http://beta.phpformatter.com/) but it's generally best to do this as you write it. What you've got here is like the "code" they scroll by really quickly in movies when someone's *hacking*. If that's just how you roll, that's fine, but if you want help here you'll need to make an effort to trim it down to a **minimal example** of your problem and clean it up.

Comment: Sorry guys, like i say im new to PHP and wrote this to get my VB.net application up and running.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and ill take that into account, im sure theres even a way of splitting all these requests into a seperate page but the time i had i had to make it post to itself , simply because of lack of knowledge.....please forgive this noob

Comment: Nothing wrong with being new to PHP. If you're just getting started, you're going to have to be careful not to pick up too many bad habits. A more gentle introduction with more structure comes from picking a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that does a lot of the heavy lifting for you and gives you tools to make your life a *lot* easier.